# How to train a CNN without lose the already trained weights (memory loss effect)

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

From what I've researched, there is nothing that can handle the "memory loss" effect by using tensorflow (which I consider the most complete library for the purpose). In this way, I would like to formulate my question relate to this.

Considering the hypothetical scenario of a large set of images that were used for training, and this training took hours to occur, gave to me an accurate weights. Now, I would like to make my model even more robust by presenting even more images, of course, without the need to present the initial set again. I'd like to add knowledge without losing the memory I already have!

Is there something in tensorflow that could handle this scenario? Or should I just train again with the whole set?

Comment: Read about checkpoints

Comment: Got it! Just found: "A good use of checkpointing is to output the model weights each time an improvement is observed during training". I was searching for the wrong term! Thank you, @user2717954!